# How to set a ready command when opening powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I mainly use powershell to run a server i.e, my first and (mostly) one command is

> python manage.py runserver

I seldom have to use other commands.

How can I configure the powershell to open the window with that command. Please note: that I already keep the powershell configured to open in the desired directory.

Comment: Use the PowerShell profile : http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2015/07/20/all-about-powershell-profiles.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use the PowerShell profile to preload anything useful in your PowerShell session (variables, functions, commands, ...) :

[All About PowerShell Profiles](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2015/07/20/all-about-powershell-profiles.aspx)

Comment: The articles list everything that are already written everywhere else. I couldn't find what I am looking for.

Comment: What did you add to your profile exactly ? You can update your question it will be easier to format code

Comment: My profile only has 
set-location c:\py\tango_with_django_project

What I want to have is when PS opens, there is a default command list as:
PS>python manage.py runserver